# non-affine transformation of GUI.matrix (c#/unity)

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, transformation, projection-matrix

I'm trying to understand GUI.matrix in unity, but there is very little documentation.

I discovered that the first quadrant is an affine transformation matrix, so I've managed to write code to scale, rotate, and skew my gui. But I want a gui that looks like it's on a screen that's on the background image, and this image has perspective. This means that I need to map parallel lines to non-parallel lines.

I'm not great on my understanding of non-affine transformations, but my main hurdle is that I have no idea what all the other elements in GUI.matrix are.

Basically, at the moment, I have a function `transformationFunction()` such that when I do

```
GUI.matrix = transformationFunction( GUI.matrix, rot, scale, shear )
```

my GUI elements are on a 'virtual screen' that is scaled, rotated, and sheared relative to my actual screen. But what I actually want is

```
GUI.matrix = transformationFunction( GUI.matrix, rot, scale, shear, someParameter/s )
```

that does not preserve parallelism, allowing me to have a GUI that is trapezoidal (for example). The 16 elements of GUI.matrix must have enough information in them to do this, I'm just not sure how that information is structured.